# exceptionorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," Position: 70

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I tried running the following query but its showing syntax error.I checked "," error in full query but couldn't find it. Can anyone explain where is the error?

```
@WebServlet("/gisBack")
public class GisBack extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String fromx = request.getParameter("fromx");
        String fromy = request.getParameter("fromy");
        String destx = request.getParameter("destinationx");
        String desty = request.getParameter("destinationy");
        String x = request.getParameter("x");
        String y = request.getParameter("y");
        //writer.println("Welome to servlet ");
        Connection conn = null;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String dburl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, "postgres", "sid");
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            //System.out.println("connection-----"+conn);
            //String query = "select * from pgr_fromAtoB('texas_roads_gcs', "+fromx+", "+fromy+", "+destx+","+desty+")"; 
            String query1 = "drop table if exists route9";
            stat.executeUpdate(query1);
            String query2 = "create table route9 as select * from pgr_fromAtoB('texas_roads_gcs', "+fromx+", "+fromy+", "+destx+","+desty+")"; 
            stat.executeUpdate(query2);
            String query = "select seq,gid,name,cost,heading from route9";
            //System.out.println(query+"=query pgr from atob");
            //ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery(query1);
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int col = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            buf.append("<html>"+"<body>"+"<table border=2   >"+"<tr>");
            for (int i = 1; i < col; i++) {
                //writer.println("column MetaData ");
                // get the column's name.
                buf.append("<th>"+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+"</th>");
                //writer.println("&emsp;&emsp;");

            }
            buf.append("</tr>");
            writer.println("<br/>");
            while(rs.next()){
                buf.append("<tr>");
                for(int i=1;i<col;i++){
                    buf.append("<td>"+rs.getString(i)+"</td>"+"&emsp;");
                    //writer.println(rs.getString(i));
                    //writer.println("&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;");
                    //System.out.println(rs.getString(i)+"=value");
                }
                buf.append("</tr>");
                //writer.println("<br/>");
            }
            buf.append("</table>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>");
            String html = buf.toString();
            writer.println(html);
            String query4 = "select sum(cost) from route9";
            ResultSet tot = stat.executeQuery(query4);
            tot.next();
            String sum = tot.getString(1);
            double sum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum);
            writer.println("<br/>");
            writer.println("<br/>");
            writer.println("Total cost is "+ sum1);

            String blockQuery1 = "update texas_roads_gcs set length=length*1000 where gid=(select gid from (select gid,length,ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText(POINT("+x+" "+y+")),geom,0.05) from texas_roads_gcs where ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText(POINT("+x+" "+y+")),geom,0.05)='t')as s)";
            stat.execute(blockQuery1);

            rs.close();
            stat.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("exception"+e);

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(conn!=null){
                try{
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: `length` is a string function, that might be giving you grief.

Comment: It's probably not the cause of the error, but you only need one subquery.  There's no need to include the results of the `ST_DWithin()` function in the SELECT clause of the inner subquery.  Also, are you sure that subquery will only return one row?

Comment: Yes, that subquery is returning a table containing gid as 2362

Comment: try to print x and y to ensure they do not contain a comma, like 1,234.56  or 1234,56 which would break the `Point` function.

Comment: I realised on running the code again(after commenting this line), the same error is still being shown. On clicking on the error, its saying source not found. Now, I don't know where to search the error. I am providing my full code above.